# Mimic a 'BarPlot3D'

Tags: plotting

I want to create a graph that looks similar to this "BarPlot3D" here [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nFHQ.png)]:

[image: Figure S13 from PCCP, 2014,16, 26184-26192]

My input for testing purposes:

```
xyz={{487, 507, 0.000687138}, {487, 512, 0}, {487, 587, 0}, {487, 591, 
  3.33204*10^-8}, {487, 596, 0}, {487, 609, 0}, {487, 639, 0}, {487, 
  640, 0}, {487, 703, 0.344578}, {487, 768, 0}, {511, 507, 0}, {511, 
  512, 0}, {511, 587, 0}, {511, 591, 0}, {511, 596, 0}, {511, 609, 
  0}, {511, 639, 0}, {511, 640, 0}, {511, 703, 0}, {511, 768, 
  3.33204*10^-8}, {595, 507, 0}, {595, 512, 0}, {595, 587, 0}, {595, 
  591, 0}, {595, 596, 0}, {595, 609, 0}, {595, 639, 
  5.41254*10^-6}, {595, 640, 0}, {595, 703, 3.33204*10^-8}, {595, 768,
   0}, {627, 507, 2.86652*10^-7}, {627, 512, 0.0227501}, {627, 587, 
  0.0227501}, {627, 591, 0}, {627, 596, 0}, {627, 609, 0}, {627, 639, 
  0}, {627, 640, 0}, {627, 703, 0}, {627, 768, 0.000159109}, {641, 
  507, 2.86652*10^-7}, {641, 512, 0}, {641, 587, 2.86652*10^-7}, {641,
   591, 0}, {641, 596, 0}, {641, 609, 0}, {641, 639, 0}, {641, 640, 
  0}, {641, 703, 0}, {641, 768, 0}, {643, 507, 0}, {643, 512, 
  0.0227501}, {643, 587, 9.86588*10^-10}, {643, 591, 0}, {643, 596, 
  0}, {643, 609, 0}, {643, 639, 0.42074}, {643, 640, 0.11507}, {643, 
  703, 0}, {643, 768, 7.93328*10^-7}, {654, 507, 7.93328*10^-7}, {654,
   512, 0}, {654, 587, 0}, {654, 591, 0}, {654, 596, 0}, {654, 609, 
  0}, {654, 639, 0}, {654, 640, 0}, {654, 703, 1.07176*10^-8}, {654, 
  768, 0}, {675, 507, 0}, {675, 512, 7.93328*10^-7}, {675, 587, 
  0.000687138}, {675, 591, 2.11245*10^-6}, {675, 596, 
  0.00466119}, {675, 609, 0}, {675, 639, 2.86652*10^-7}, {675, 640, 
  0}, {675, 703, 0.158655}, {675, 768, 0}, {682, 507, 0}, {682, 512, 
  0}, {682, 587, 0.0359303}, {682, 591, 0.211855}, {682, 596, 
  0}, {682, 609, 0}, {682, 639, 0}, {682, 640, 0}, {682, 703, 
  0}, {682, 768, 0.0000133457}, {712, 507, 0}, {712, 512, 0}, {712, 
  587, 0.344578}, {712, 591, 0.000072348}, {712, 596, 
  0.000336929}, {712, 609, 0}, {712, 639, 0}, {712, 640, 
  0.00819754}, {712, 703, 0}, {712, 768, 0}}
```

So far, I came up with the following:

```
bar[x_, y_, z_] := Cuboid[{x - 10, y - 2, 0}, {x + 10, y + 2, z}];
Show[
 Plot3D[None, {x, 470, 780}, {y, 470, 780},
  PlotRange -> {0, All},
  ViewPoint -> {1000, 1000, 600},
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
  AxesLabel -> {"Triplet Excited States \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(m\
\)]\) (nm)", 
    "Singlet Excited States \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(n\)]\) (nm)", 
    Rotate["\[LeftAngleBracket]\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \
\(n\)]\)|\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(H\), \
\(SO\)]\)|\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(m\)]\)\[RightAngleBracket] \
(1/cm)", 90 Degree]},
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium],
  TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold],
  BoxStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick],
  Boxed -> False,
  Axes -> {True, True, True},
  FaceGrids -> Dynamic[Sign /@ DiagonalMatrix[-{1, 1, 1}]]],
 Graphics3D[Map[bar @@ # &, Flatten[xyz, 1]]],
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: my version of the previous image]

Am I at a dead end or what would be the way to go on?
What other solutions would be better?

The labeling looks like as if it has been done afterwards, so maybe I will choose the same way for that.

---

[1] [*Phys. Chem. Chem. Phys.*, **2014**, *16*, 26184-26192](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/C4CP03540B)

Comment: I always tried to separate the labeling from the plotmaking for this reason.  First make the plot in *Mathematica*, then import it as a bitmap to some other program for adding text.  I'd just copy and paste it into Inkscape, use its $\LaTeX$ plugin to make better labels I could rotate and resize.  Then if I need to redo the plot, I just replace that element of the figure.

Comment: do you know the formula for z?

Comment: There is no formula. They come from a parsed matrix, but in this example they are random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xyz = {{487, 507, 0.000687138}, {487, 512, 0}, {487, 587, 0}, {487, 
    591, 3.33204*10^-8}, {487, 596, 0}, {487, 609, 0}, {487, 639, 
    0}, {487, 640, 0}, {487, 703, 0.344578}, {487, 768, 0}, {511, 507,
     0}, {511, 512, 0}, {511, 587, 0}, {511, 591, 0}, {511, 596, 
    0}, {511, 609, 0}, {511, 639, 0}, {511, 640, 0}, {511, 703, 
    0}, {511, 768, 3.33204*10^-8}, {595, 507, 0}, {595, 512, 0}, {595,
     587, 0}, {595, 591, 0}, {595, 596, 0}, {595, 609, 0}, {595, 639, 
    5.41254*10^-6}, {595, 640, 0}, {595, 703, 3.33204*10^-8}, {595, 
    768, 0}, {627, 507, 2.86652*10^-7}, {627, 512, 0.0227501}, {627, 
    587, 0.0227501}, {627, 591, 0}, {627, 596, 0}, {627, 609, 
    0}, {627, 639, 0}, {627, 640, 0}, {627, 703, 0}, {627, 768, 
    0.000159109}, {641, 507, 2.86652*10^-7}, {641, 512, 0}, {641, 587,
     2.86652*10^-7}, {641, 591, 0}, {641, 596, 0}, {641, 609, 
    0}, {641, 639, 0}, {641, 640, 0}, {641, 703, 0}, {641, 768, 
    0}, {643, 507, 0}, {643, 512, 0.0227501}, {643, 587, 
    9.86588*10^-10}, {643, 591, 0}, {643, 596, 0}, {643, 609, 
    0}, {643, 639, 0.42074}, {643, 640, 0.11507}, {643, 703, 0}, {643,
     768, 7.93328*10^-7}, {654, 507, 7.93328*10^-7}, {654, 512, 
    0}, {654, 587, 0}, {654, 591, 0}, {654, 596, 0}, {654, 609, 
    0}, {654, 639, 0}, {654, 640, 0}, {654, 703, 1.07176*10^-8}, {654,
     768, 0}, {675, 507, 0}, {675, 512, 7.93328*10^-7}, {675, 587, 
    0.000687138}, {675, 591, 2.11245*10^-6}, {675, 596, 
    0.00466119}, {675, 609, 0}, {675, 639, 2.86652*10^-7}, {675, 640, 
    0}, {675, 703, 0.158655}, {675, 768, 0}, {682, 507, 0}, {682, 512,
     0}, {682, 587, 0.0359303}, {682, 591, 0.211855}, {682, 596, 
    0}, {682, 609, 0}, {682, 639, 0}, {682, 640, 0}, {682, 703, 
    0}, {682, 768, 0.0000133457}, {712, 507, 0}, {712, 512, 0}, {712, 
    587, 0.344578}, {712, 591, 0.000072348}, {712, 596, 
    0.000336929}, {712, 609, 0}, {712, 639, 0}, {712, 640, 
    0.00819754}, {712, 703, 0}, {712, 768, 0}};

{ymin, ymax} = MinMax[xyz[[All, 2]]];

bar[x_, y_, z_] := {
   ColorData["BrightBands"][Rescale[y, {ymin, ymax}]],
   Cuboid[{x - 10, y - 2, 0}, {x + 10, y + 2, z}]};
```

You can put everything into the `Graphics3D` use of an empty `Plot` along with `Show` is unnecessary.

```
Graphics3D[bar @@@ xyz,
 PlotRange -> {{470, 780}, {470, 780}, All},
 ViewPoint -> {1000, 1000, 600},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium],
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold],
 BoxStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick],
 Boxed -> False,
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {
   Rotate[
    StringForm["``Triplet Excited States `` (nm)", Spacer[40], 
     Subscript[T, m]], 26 Degree],
   Rotate[
    StringForm["Singlet Excited States `` (nm)``", Subscript[S, n], 
     Spacer[40]], -24 Degree],
   Rotate[
    StringForm[
     "\n\[LeftAngleBracket]``|``|``\[RightAngleBracket] (1/cm)", 
     Subscript[S, n], Subscript[H, SO], Subscript[T, m]], 
    90 Degree]},
 FaceGrids -> DiagonalMatrix[-{1, 1, 1}],
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may use `Histogram3D`.

The data is first `GatherBy` the x-values in bins of width 5. Each set is converted into `WeightedData` with sets of all zero weights dropped. The remaining sets are plotted by `Histogram3D` with bin widths of 5 on the x-axis and 10 on the y-axis.

With `xyz` as defined in the OP.

```
With[{dat = 
   Query[All, WeightedData[#[[All, ;; 2]], #[[All, -1]]] &, FailureAction -> "Drop"]@
     GatherBy[xyz, Ceiling[First@#, 5] &]},
 Histogram3D[dat, {{5}, {10}},
  ChartStyle -> (Opacity[1, ColorData[{"Indexed", "NeonColor"}]@#] & /@Range[Length@dat]),
  PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, Automatic, {None, Automatic}},
  Boxed -> False,
  BoxRatios -> 1,
  FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}},
  AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None, None},
  ImageSize -> Large
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: While this is technically a good idea, I think by using a histogram and binning, close values would be combined. I'd say this is physically not right as every single bar represents sth unique.